# Extract values from a column following a pattern and place them into different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I copied and pasted table data from a PDF. In this operation, the correct rows and columns from the PDF are lost, I end up with all the data into on single column in Google Sheets.

What I try to do is to be able to automate the placement of the data into several columns. In my below example we can see the data follows a pattern: data is organised every 3 rows

Start table:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Requirement 1 |
| To do |
| Mark |
| Requirement 2 |
| Done |
| Steve |
| Requirement 3 |
| To do |
| Steve |

I tried several ways with arrayformula, split, flatten, etc. I just do not know how to repeat action every 3 rows.

Expected result:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Requirement 1 | To do | Mark |
| Requirement 2 | Done | Steve |
| Requirement 3 | To do | Steve |

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this formula:*

```js
=wraprows(A:A,3)
```

Comment: That is too easy !! ;)  Many thanks I was trying too complicated